# how to call javascript function inside thickbox?

Tags: javascript, ajax, thickbox

My javascript function not working inside thickbox.

```
i have a function **searchRealtors()**,
```

it will get invoked on keyUp and it works if loaded the page directly.But inside thickbox its not..

**My Code**

```
function searchRealtors()
{
   alert('Hello');
   //and some ajax call
}
```

**in my PHP file**

```
onkeyup="searchRealtors();"
```

Any Help?
Pls visit directly http://imlsnetwork.com/guest

to see it in thickbox visit http://imlsnetwork.com/ and click on Signup->clients join here button

Answer (score 0):

You have missed a ";". The javascript function should be called as

```
  onkeyup = "searchRealtors();"

                             ^here
```

Comment: You added it now. Did that help?

Comment: Sorry i have alredy done it. the problem is occuring only the page loads inside thickbox. otherwise its working fine..

Comment: Pls visit directly http://imlsnetwork.com/guest.

And in thickbox visit http://imlsnetwork.com/ and click on Signup->clients join here button

Answer (score -1):

If you have single option then use checkbox.
it you have multiple options  then make tichboxes femaly same and you may use onchange / on select.